# Blender animation with static hair particle system, single-frame render anomaly

Tags: rendering, animation, particles, hair

I was following Blender Guru's Introduction Tutorial, everything went fine for creating the desired static image.
[image: Initial Donut Image]
I'm using Blender 2.79b on Windows 8.1.

It uses a Hair particle system for the donut sprinkles.  I wanted to do a 3-second animation with a small amount of camera movement, like a smooth slider, and it generally worked, but with two glitches at frame 22 and frame 27.  Here's the 3-second video, 5.5 MBytes:
[Donut_001.mp4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9yl4wtqdtokn4xw/donut_001.mp4?dl=0)
It looks as though the seed for the particle system jumps to a new value on those frames and then jumps back on the next frame.  So, it's a strange one-frame anomaly.  It's strange, the ViewPort Render View looks different from the Final Render, with regard to the sprinkles on the pink donut.  It looks to me like a strange Blender bug.  But I am a total beginner, so I'm not sure about that.  I've looked to see if I have accidentally added keyframes on frame 22 and frame 79 and done something strange to the sprinkles particle system, but I don't see anything like that.  This screenshot shows the keyframes at frame 0 and 90 for moving the camera.
[image: No Key Frame at Frame 22 or 79]
There aren't any other keyframes on the sprinkles particle system.

I searched for bug reports like this; Here is the closest one I found:
https://developer.blender.org/T53045
But it's not quite describing my problem.

Here are the files to reproduce the problem:

[BlenderGuruTutorial011.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a59qgichd5x6n8b/BlenderGuruTutorial011.blend?dl=0)

[ChristmasTreeJacked.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2zl5velk5a9c28/ChristmasTreeJacked.jpg?dl=0)

[wood.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0azhj2wbvb8vmq4/wood.jpg?dl=0)

[wood_normal.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aehfmfhbs5oqnyy/wood_normal.jpg?dl=0)

Any comments or suggestions would be most welcome!

Thank you,

Lloyd

Comment: oops, sorry, the second glitch was at frame 79, not 27.

Comment: I've just filed it as a bug report.

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T58562

Comment: Here is the .blend file with all the supporting files packed into it:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkcgdwj6ptj30cj/BlenderGuruTutorial012.blend?dl=0

Comment: I've tried rendering the animation using Blender 2.80 beta, and the bug is gone:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rcyp6d3dgeng4r/donut_002.mp4?dl=0